# Unusual polygon shapes when using tree_hulls?

Tags: lidar, las, lidr, catalog

The following script uses lidR to segment trees and output tree hulls (i.e. polygons representing individual tree canopies). Input data are a directory of laz files and a catalog is used to manage the processing.

```
library(lidR)
library(rgdal)

my_tree_detection_method <- function(cluster, ws)
{
  las <- readLAS(cluster)
  if (is.empty(las)) return(NULL)

  las_n <- lasnormalize(las, tin())
  chm  <- grid_canopy(las_n, 0.25, pitfree(c(0,2,5,10,15), c(0,1), subcircle = 0.2))
  algo = watershed(chm, th = 4)
  trees <- lastrees(las_n, algo)

  # Remove the buffers
  trees_no_buffer <- lasfilter(trees, buffer == 0)
  return(trees_no_buffer)
}

ws <- "/path/to/laz/directory"
ctg <- readLAScatalog(ws)
lidR:::catalog_laxindex(ctg) 

opt_chunk_buffer(ctg) <- 10
opt_chunk_size(ctg) <- 200 

opt <- list(need_buffer = TRUE) 
output <- catalog_apply(ctg, my_tree_detection_method, ws = 5, .options = opt)
output <- do.call(rbind, output)

hulls  = tree_hulls(output, func = .stdmetrics)
writeOGR(hulls, dsn = "/path/to/dir", layer = "hulls", driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```

---

[image]

---

When I write the hulls to shapefile to inspect the results, the hulls appear very distorted. I would expect thousands of small polygons representing tree canopies. What might be causing this distortion?

The following from the [documentation](https://github.com/Jean-Romain/lidR/wiki/Segment-individual-trees-and-compute-metrics#compute-some-metrics-and-hulls) is what I would expect to see:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You found why there is no `lastrees` methods available for a `LAScatalog` yet in `lidR`. You did not consider the continuity of the tree IDs. In each chunk the trees are labeled from 1 to `n`. So in chunk 1 you have a tree labeled 1 and you have another tree labeled 1 in chunks 2,3,4, ...

At the end you merged everything and you have several points tagged 1 spread on the coverage. `tree_hull` takes all the points tagged 1 and makes the hull of the tree number 1. And this hull is meaningless.

Because the chunks are processed independently and potentially in parallel it is almost impossible to maintain data integrity. You must either find a method to maintain the continuity of the IDs (I'm trying for 2 years) or you must build a more complex function. The following is something I did for a demo. It computes the hulls for each chunk and using the tree tops it removes the hull of the trees that are outside the chunks (i.e in the buffer).

```
my_process = function(cl) {
  las = readLAS(cl)
  if (is.empty(las)) return(NULL)
  bbox = extent(cl)
  las = lasfilterduplicates(las)
  chm = grid_canopy(las, 0.5, p2r())
  ttops = tree_detection(las, lmf(3, 5))
  las = lastrees(las, dalponte2016(chm, ttops))
  p = tree_metrics(las)
  p = crop(p, bbox)
  m = tree_hulls(las, func = .stdtreemetrics)
  m = m[m$treeID %in% p$treeID,]
  return(m)
}

options = list(automerge = TRUE) # available from v2.2.0
m = catalog_apply(ctg, my_process, .options = options)
```